# Make a local change without committing

Tags: git

There's this file on my project that I need to modify whenever I run the web app locally.  I basically need to comment out a function call to an external service.  I realize this should be properly fixed by making a fake client or something, but the code in question is owned by another team.  I want to be able to comment out the code, and then make a bunch of other changes without worrying about accidentally pushing the stubbed out code to master.  I realize I can commit individual files, but this is a pain and I'd rather just be able to do `git commit -am "bla bla"`.  I guess I could add the problem file to my `.gitignore`, but I do work with the file occasionally so this is somewhat inconvenient.  Is there a better way to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using `update-index` here:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <your_file.ext>
```

This option will tell Git to temporarily ignore changes to `your_file.ext`.  Running `git status` will not report this file, even if you made changes to it.

Note that if you accidentally do `git add` to your file directly, it will still be added to the index.  But this option is a safety precaution which should at least make it harder for you to push changes to `your_file.ext`.

Comment: Another option is to commit those changes to a different branch and keep that rebased atop `master`. This way you have a clear view of your own changes and there is no magic going on. `update-index --assume-unchanged` can be a cause of confusion.

Comment: @jsageryd Good suggestion, and I always feel that if there is a file where sometimes it should be versioned, and sometimes not, that the root problem is a workflow issue.  Any solution is really something of a hack.

Comment: `skip-worktree` is preferred over `assume-unchanged`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630849/git-difference-between-assume-unchanged-and-skip-worktree/13631525#13631525)

Comment: @1615903 I have read your link, interesting, I did not know about this.